# Track file by extended attribute value

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal, command, command-prompt

So I am trying to make a script that references other files. I want to be able to keep track of the file even if it moves. So I was thinking if I could assign a file a unique value then I could find the location of the file by searching by the unique value I assigned it.

Is there a better way to do this?

Basically I'd like to be able to find a file from a value it has as an extended attribute. But I don't know if this is possible.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the inode number (show it with `ls -i /some/file`) which will be unique per file and which does not change when the file is changed or moved, UNLESS you move the file to a different partition. If you don't need to track files over multiple partitions than this would be a very easy solution.

To find a file by inode number you can use `find -inum <inode number>`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to move the file across filesystems, you can use the command [setfattr](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setfattr) to set extended attributes to file, note: your kernel must be able to do this.
There aren't one-shot command to find the file but you can create a simple script to search the file by your unique key.
To set to yourfile a key similar to *user.unique* and a string value as you like, e.g.: *n1234*

```
setfattr -n user.unique -v n1234 yourfile
```

to retrieve the value you can use the command getfattr

```
getfattr -n user.unique yourfile
```

or to get all extended file attributes:

```
getfattr -d yourfile
```

To test if your kernel is able to handle extended attributes on type of your filesystems:

```
zcat /proc/config.gz | grep FS_XATTR
```

To write a simple script to search using extended attributes you can refer to this [Hack](http://eduunix.ccut.edu.cn/index2/html/linux/OReilly.Linux.Server.Hacks.Volume.Two.Dec.2005/0596100825/morelnxsvrhks-CHP-5-SECT-10.html#morelnxsvrhks-CHP-5-SECT-10.5); on the same page you can read more about extended attributes.